How to select 5 row columns into new columns
I have 2 table I am join from, namely Requests and RequestComments
1 Request can have multiple comment
Request Table Data



Reference
Client Surname
Client Address




1
Adams
Test Address


2
Jaco
Test Address



RequestComments Table Data



RequestRef
DateCreated
Sender
Comment




1
2023/01/01
Sender_ONE
Com_ONE


1
2023/01/02
Sender_TWO
Com_TWO


1
2023/01/03
Sender_ONE
Com_THREE


1
2023/01/04
Sender_ONE
Com_FOUR


1
2023/01/05
Sender_ONE
Com_FIVE


2
2023/01/01
Test_1
Test_Com_1


2
2023/01/02
Test_2
Test_Com_2


2
2023/01/03
Test_3
Test_Com_3



select
    r.[Reference],
    c.DateCreated,
    c.[Sender],
    c.[Comment],
    r.[Client Surname],
    r.[Client Address]
from Requests r
cross apply (
    select top 5
        rc.DateCreated,
        rc.[Sender],
        rc.[Comment]
    from RequestComments rc
    where rc.[Reference] = r.[RequestRef]
    order by rc.DateCreated
) c

I need to need to get the DateCreated, Sender and Comment in 5 (only 5) different columns within the same row without duplicates.
Currently rows are duplicating.
I have also tried a pivot with no luck.
My output should look something like this



Reference
DateCreated
Sender
Comment
DateCreated
Sender
Comment
DateCreated
Sender
Comment
DateCreated
Sender
Comment
DateCreated
Sender
Comment
Client Surname
Client Address




1
2023/01/01
Sender_ONE
Com_ONE
2023/01/02
Sender_TWO
Com_TWO
2023/01/03
Sender_THREE
Com_THREE
2023/01/04
Sender_FOUR
Com_FOUR
2023/01/05
Sender_FIVE
Com_FIVE
Adams
Test Address


2
2023/01/01
Test_1
Test_Com_1
2023/01/02
Test_2
Test_Com_2
2023/01/03
Test_3
Test_Com_3






Jackson
Test Address




While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Try harder, pivot is the answer. You might need a row_number to differentiate the 5 rows, but this too has been solved many times before.

Does this answer your question? Group by column and multiple Rows into One Row multiple columns
